# How to avoid desaturation when using glossy material

Tags: materials, shaders

Most materials is simulater with a white specular component. Now, if I mix the specular component with the diffuse component, the diffuse component becomes desaturated. How can I avoid this. The problem arises in Cycles, Blender internal, and in other CG lightning models.

For an example, see http://www.chocofur.com/6-shadersamptextures.html, especially "Reflection factor"

Comment: Give the glossy some color maybe?

Comment: How mutch? And the specular component will no longer be white.

Comment: Don't mix Cycles an Blender Internal shading because they are totally different. In BI you get specular reflection but Cycles doesn't know this - it knows only reflectivity and its roughness. All materials in Cycles are reflective in contrast with BI. When you mix your shader with some white glossy - expect your object picking (reflecting) more color from surroundings (grey bacground or enviro etc.). Can you post pictures of what you have and how would you like it to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Compositor & Render Layers.  Enable Glossy direct.  Isolate/Transform gloss/specular with color ramp.  [Alpha Over] node to combine images.  The image below isolates some specular/gloss.

[image]

- When you use the mix shader you have an option to specify the mix .. labelled [fac].  Change the setting to suit your taste.
- Consider rendering the image once as diffuse and once with specular.  Use the compositor to threshold with color ramp and choose the best color. PR or NPR? Suit to your tastes. More work.
- Use more elaborate nodes in the materials to change the effect of specular. More work.